# How can I upgrade my processor from X3065 to X3220?

Tags: dell-poweredge, intel, xeon, central-processing-unit

I have a Dell Poweredge R200 server which has an ancient Xeon 3065 processor. I see in the servers specs that it can accommodate Xeon 3200 series, but not sure if I buy a bare-boned Xeon 3220 processor (without heatsink etc.) , will it fit easily on motherboard? If not, what exactly should I buy to upgrade my processor? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will physically fit yes, they're both LGA775 chips but the 3220 has a TDP of nearly twice that of the 3065, you may have heat management issues that would affect the life of your server.

Comment: I see the point about TDP. What about X3320? I just bought a new X3320. I have no idea if it comes with a heatsink or not. Do you reckon it will fit on the server? and will have heat issues?

Comment: well the 3320 is only 95w so should be better than the 3220, how about an L3360? same TDP as your current chip, same socket - if your BIOS supports it then you should be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You wan a Dell #311-8328 CPU Upgrade kit. Doesn't void the warranty and comes with a properly sized heat sink (might be the same, might not).

Comment: So do you think buying a Dell upgrade kit the only safe way to do the upgrade? If not, what consideration should I have when I buy a CPU from elsewhere? thanks

Comment: I don't deal with "custom modified" servers much, as the warranty and support SLAs are typically well outside a normal business's requirements. Any X3220 processor should work; it would be the heatsink and any other parts that are included in the kit that you'd be missing (along with the warranty and support of course).